# I am unable to run cube js backend server

Tags: javascript, cube.js

I received this error while run the back end server of Cube js. using npm run dev to started the server. while accessing a given link. It shows error like below. Help me to resolve

```
  Cannot GET /cubejs-api/v1
```

Comment: Please post sample code

Comment: @AdityaBhave I got the answer. Actually the problem is i didn't pass the query values like. measures, dimensions.............

Answer (score 1):

There's no such API path `/cubejs-api/v1`. I believe you're looking for `/cubejs-api/v1/load`: https://cube.dev/docs/rest-api#api-reference-v-1-load.

Answer (score 0):

This misconception comes because of the following code generated by CubeJS:

```
const cubejsApi = cubejs(
   "<API Auth>",
   { apiUrl: API_URL + "/cubejs-api/v1" }
);
```

What you in fact want to do on *Postman* or what have you is use the following url to run queries add **load** after v1.

Example

```
{{HOST}}/cubejs-api/v1/load?query={
  "measures": [
  "UserOrderValue.minDate",
  "UserOrderValue.maxDate",
  "UserOrderValue.lastWeek",
  "UserOrderValue.lastMonth",
  "UserOrderValue.lastQuarter",
  "UserOrderValue.lastYear"
  ]
}
```